# SQL: find overlapping cell values across the same column of many tables

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with postgresql and I'm a bit of a newbie to SQL, generally.

I'm attempting to write a query that checks if a values overlap between a master list and multiple tables. The values in question are usernames and the multiple tables (30 in all) each represent event data for different games.

Each game has its own table with identical column headings. 30 tables that have identical columns something like this...:

table name: game1...game30

```
   USERNAME                                 EVENT_TIMESTAMP       OTHER_FELIDS
   2592761928AF756E45891527ED49A7A9         2016-02-01 02:38:05   ...
   79460FE440ADB429F542D2F08A763D50         2016-02-01 02:38:35   ...
   3945B26DD9F6FD2D49574856ECF9FA7D         2016-02-01 02:44:12   ...
   A597AE2CF6E15497EE7AC2A02CEEB32E         2016-02-01 02:46:57   ...
   65DE308FC39980CCD37DBDE8A432F221         2016-02-01 02:46:57   ...
   ...
```

I have a list of specified user_ids that I've used to create a "key table" I'm attempting to write a query that will tell me whether or not any of the users in my key table list show up in the game's event data. 
My key table is only two columns and looks something like this:

table name: username_key

```
EMAIL          HASHED_EMAIL
asd0@asd.com   79460FE440ADB429F542D2F08A763D50
asd1@asd.com   0C450FAC330D69A315604CDE61C7A65E
asd2@asd.com   F2D7714CBA1048A940231087549F1D95
bob@asd.com    FE793A075E0633441B5EE5535FAAEDD2
asd7@asd.com   47FAFD07C174B81BADD28AD9BE64E26B
...
```

(Note: the username in both the games tables and the key table are hash encrypted emails, hence the name "HASHED_EMAILS")

My query currently looks like this:

```
create temp table players as select ky.hashed_email from username_key as ky 
    inner join game1 g1 on ky.hashed_email = g1.username 
    inner join game2 g2 on ky.hashed_email = g2.username
    inner join game3 g3 on ky.hashed_email = g3.username
    inner join game4 g4 on ky.hashed_email = g4.username
    ...
    inner join game30 g30 on ky.hashed_email = g30.username
```

When I try to run this query it hangs for a long long time... Hours and eventually times out.

I'm hoping to return a list of users that show up in one or more of the game events tables, or return an empty list (which would tell me that no one in my key table list has played the games).

Am I on the right track with my query?
Is there a faster/more efficient way to accomplish this task then the way I'm doing it?
How would you, a postgresql expert, solve this problem (finding specific occurrences of usernames across many different tables)?

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: what is the problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to see if a given list of users have ever generated events (ie played a game) across many different tables (each table holds data for a game). I don't really care what the output looks like as long as I can confirm or deny that events appear for those users.

Comment: post your tables, show some sample data, show the expected result

Comment: put `explain select ky.players from username_key as ky...ETC` here - it wont take any time, but will give us and idea of what tables you have

Comment: @VaoTsun thanks, I've edited my question for clarity. Let me know if it's easier to understand?

Comment: @JoeM05 no, no - `explain` is a part of SQL statement, not just a favour - put explain plan here

Comment: ah, okay. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

If you care for a user being in any of the tables, not multiple ones, you have the following alternatives:

- `IN` with `UNION`:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM players WHERE hashed_email IN (
      SELECT username FROM game1
      UNION SELECT username FROM game2
      UNION SELECT username FROM game3
      ...
  )
  ```
- `IN` with `OR`:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM player WHERE hashed_email IN (SELECT username FROM game1)
      OR hashed_email IN (SELECT username FROM game2)
      OR hashed_email IN (SELECT username FROM game3)
      ...
  ```
- `EXISTS`:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM player WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM game1 WHERE username=hashed_email)
      OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM game2 WHERE username=hashed_email)
      OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM game3 WHERE username=hashed_email)
      ...
  ```

There are probably quite a few other alternatives. You should probably use `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to find out which is the more efficient, though I wouldn't be surprised if all three resulted in a substantially similar query plan.

Note that having an appropriate index on `username` in each of the `game*` tables would of course help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer jcaron when you say "any of the tables" does that include the key table? Because, of course they will be present there.

Comment: I meant any of the `game*` tables.

Comment: ah, thanks... I'll accept the answer, I just haven't had a chance to try the solution. The server went down and no one is in the office to get it back up during the holiday break!